# SwiftUI shape fill body

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to construct a view in SwiftUI, where the user can keep zooming in and out, and show elements across the view. But the rectangle keeps the size of the window, and scales down when zooming out instead of filling the body. The body (black) correctly fills the window.

How do you make the white rectangle fill the body when zooming out?
[image: white rectangle partially filling the black body of the window]

(Must be run in an app instead of preview)

```swift
import SwiftUI

func rgb (_ count: Int) -> [Color]{
    let colors = [Color.red, Color.green, Color.blue]
    var arr: [Color] = []
    for i in 0..<count {
        arr.append(colors[i%3])
    }
    return arr
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
         
        let colors = rgb(20)
        
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.white)
                
                .frame(minWidth: 0,
                       maxWidth: .infinity,
                       minHeight: 0,
                       maxHeight: .infinity,
                       alignment: .center)
               
             ForEach(colors.indices.reversed(), id: \.self) { i in
                 Circle()
                    .size(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .fill(colors[i])
                    .offset(x: 100.0*CGFloat(i), y: 100.0*CGFloat(i))
                        }
        }
        .drawingGroup()
        .scaleEffect(scale)
        .gesture(MagnificationGesture()
                    .onChanged {self.scale = $0})
        .background(Color.black)
        .frame(minWidth: 0,
               maxWidth: .infinity,
               minHeight: 0,
               maxHeight: .infinity,
               alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

Comment: Works as you expect for me. Xcode 12.3, Big Sur 11.1.

Comment: Running the app on Apple Silicon, Intel and iPhone, all latest versions, the problem still persists for me. Any chance you can try with the updated code, to test if all 20 circles are displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Functioning example for this use case, with rectangle removed from ZStack:

```swift
import SwiftUI

func rgb (_ count: Int) -> [Color]{
    let colors = [Color.red, Color.green, Color.blue]
    var arr: [Color] = []
    for i in 0..<count {
        arr.append(colors[i%3])
    }
    return arr
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var colorIndex = 0
    var bgColor: Color { rgb(3)[colorIndex%3] }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let colors = rgb(20)
        
        ZStack {
            ForEach(colors.indices.reversed(), id: \.self) { i in
                Circle()
                    .size(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .fill(colors[i])
                    .offset(x: 100.0*CGFloat(i), y: 100.0*CGFloat(i))
            }
        }
        .drawingGroup()
        .scaleEffect(scale)
        .background(bgColor)
        .gesture(MagnificationGesture()
                    .onChanged {scale = $0})
        .gesture(TapGesture().onEnded({colorIndex+=1}))
    }
}
```

However it does not fix the problem of the shape not scaling to the body size.

Answer (score 0):

I put this an an answer to show a screenshot. The second bit of code behaves very inconsistently. I never see 20 circles. It will zoom, but seems to then be caught in some other view. It is very strange behavior and tough to explain. While the screenshot is here, I could run it 20 times and get 20 different screenshots if I zoom and/or resize the window. I am not on Apple silicon, so your first post may be a bug in implementation on Apple silicon. Wouldn't be the first.
[image]

Comment: Yep, just tried on intel, and it causes weird behaviours.